# How to create dynamic row with angular Js with 2 columns

Tags: html, angularjs

[image]I have list that I need to traverse in using angular js. I want to create row dynamically with two column and each column should show different element(record) info from list.

Comment: Please provide some sample code if possible.

Comment: Yes, at least the `list` you are referring to

Comment: if i understand needs each row of your list be the columns, provide the list please

Comment: List:{Name:Ajay,CaseId:1555,Date:07/13/2017},{Name:Atul,CaseId:16789,Date:09/08/2016} I want to display all info for Ajay in one column and all info for Atul in other column

Comment: List is an array of objects?

Comment: yes it is array of objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-repeat` directive to traverse `list` item. Which means whenever you want to push element in DOM, do push it inside collection `listItems`, `ng-repeat` will take care of rest.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in listItems">
     <td>{{item.property1}}</td>
     <td>{{item.property2}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my pleasure, but why :( ?

Comment: I am getting records from db which will have name,caseid,closed date,other info for each user.I am using ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple...

I created an example.

Plunker link: [`Click here`](https://plnkr.co/edit/1JfaGZUjA0hLJSUyBBt8?p=preview)

Note: I created a dummy example for you. You have to maintain some code according to your array.

Comment: what if I want to display firstname and lastname in one column and other frstname and lastname in another column

Comment: Then place ng-repeat on <td></td> tag.

Comment: scenario is my row should be  add dynamically and there will be always two column. there will only two records in one row

Comment: please post your array or object (data) so that we can give you best solution.

Comment: Array=[{Name:Ajay,CaseId:1555,Date:07/13/2017},{Name:Atul,CaseId:16789,Date:09/08/2017},{Name:Ram,CaseId:16722,Date:05/04/2016}, {Name:Atul,CaseId:16789,Date:09/08/2016} ]

Comment: Can you say me which two columns do you want? Because here there are three fields name, caseid, date.

Comment: Array=[{Name:Ajay,CaseId:1555,Date:07/13/2017},{Name:Atul,CaseId:16789,Date:09/08/2017},{Name:Ram,CaseId:16722,Date:05/04/2016}, {Name:Rajeevl,CaseId:16780,Date:09/08/2016} ] what I want is  info of Ajay and Atul in one row but each will be in diff column and on new row

Comment: All info about one user in on column like name,CaseId and Date for Atul in one column and All three fileds of Ajay in another column

Comment: how can I upload image here. So that I can tell you waht I want exactly

Comment: I created a plunker for you.. go through with this.. go there and see is it you actually you want? This is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/1JfaGZUjA0hLJSUyBBt8?p=preview

Comment: I want Ram And Atul(2nd) on new line.There should be only  two records on one row

Comment: hey I have uploaded image in my question.Could you please have look at it.thanks

Comment: Okay, i am updating my answer

Comment: yes,I updated my answer. Note: I used bootstrap to manage blocks of div. You can also use that or you can apply your own css. Remember without css it is not possible to handle UI that you have said. So css and styles I have given there are strongly required. Go there once again. And do up if it is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in **controller** have your list-array

```
vm.myList = [{key:'value', key2: 'value2'}, {key:'value', key2: 'value2'}];
```

in **html** use the directive `ng-repeat` to iterate over the array

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <th>Key</th>
     <th>Key2</th>
   </tbdoy>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.myList">
       <td>{{item.key}}</td>
       <td>{{item.key2}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

if wann to add more rows in **controller** push it to the array

```
vm.myList.push({key:'newValue', key2:'otherValue'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ng-repeat in tr element , you should use it in td element if you want column based dynamics